# Fail when tried to run rocket emulator

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-assembly, riscv

Im using centos and riscv tool rocketchip.I'm tried to run benchmarks in the emulator with the default rocket RV64 but I got this error :

```
    make -C /mnt/vol_NFS_Zener/WD_ESPEC/RISCV/ris/rocket-chip/firrtl SBT="java -Xmx2G -Xss8M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -jar /mnt/vol_NFS_Zener/WD_ESPEC/RISCV/ris/rocket-chip/sbt-launch.jar" root_dir=/mnt/vol_NFS_Zener/WD_ESPEC/RISCV/ris/rocket-chip/firrtl build-scala
    make[1]: Entering directory `/mnt/vol_NFS_Zener/WD_ESPEC/RISCV/ris/rocket-chip/firrtl'
    java -Xmx2G -Xss8M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -jar /mnt/vol_NFS_Zener/WD_ESPEC/RISCV/ris/rocket-chip/sbt-launch.jar "assembly"
    OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256M; support was removed in 8.0
    [info] Loading project definition from /mnt/vol_NFS_Zener/WD_ESPEC/RISCV/ris/rocket-chip/firrtl/project
    [info] Updating {file:/mnt/vol_NFS_Zener/WD_ESPEC/RISCV/ris/rocket-chip/firrtl/project/}firrtl-build...
    [info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
    [info] Done updating.
    [warn] Found version conflict(s) in library dependencies; some are suspected to be binary incompatible:
    [warn] 
    [warn]  * xml-apis:xml-apis:1.3.04 is selected over 2.0.2
    [warn]      +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-script:1.8            (depends on 1.3.04)
    [warn]      +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-anim:1.8              (depends on 1.3.04)
    [warn]      +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-transcoder:1.8        (depends on 1.3.04)
    [warn]      +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-bridge:1.8            (depends on 1.3.04)
    [warn]      +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-svg-dom:1.8           (depends on 1.3.04)
    [warn]      +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-parser:1.8            (depends on 1.3.04)
    [warn]      +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-dom:1.8               (depends on 1.3.04)
    [warn]      +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-css:1.8               (depends on 1.3.04)
    [warn]      +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-ext:1.8               (depends on 1.3.04)
    [warn]      +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-extension:1.8         (depends on 1.3.04)
    [warn]      +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-svggen:1.8            (depends on 1.3.04)
    [warn]      +- xalan:xalan:2.7.0                                  (depends on 2.0.2)
    [warn] 
    [warn] Run 'evicted' to see detailed eviction warnings
    usage: git ls-remote [--heads] [--tags]  [-u <exec> | --upload-pack <exec>] <repository> <refs>...
java.util.NoSuchElementException: head of empty stream
        at scala.collection.immutable.Stream$Empty$.head(Stream.scala:1028)
        at scala.collection.immutable.Stream$Empty$.head(Stream.scala:1026)
        at com.typesafe.sbt.SbtGit$$anonfun$buildSettings$11.apply(SbtGit.scala:138)
        at com.typesafe.sbt.SbtGit$$anonfun$buildSettings$11.apply(SbtGit.scala:122)
        at sbt.Init$Value$$anonfun$apply$13.apply(Settings.scala:609)
        at sbt.EvaluateSettings$$anonfun$sbt$EvaluateSettings$$constant$1.apply(INode.scala:163)
        at sbt.EvaluateSettings$$anonfun$sbt$EvaluateSettings$$constant$1.apply(INode.scala:163)
        at sbt.EvaluateSettings$MixedNode.evaluate0(INode.scala:175)
        at sbt.EvaluateSettings$INode.evaluate(INode.scala:135)
        at sbt.EvaluateSettings$$anonfun$sbt$EvaluateSettings$$submitEvaluate$1.apply$mcV$sp(INode.scala:69)
        at sbt.EvaluateSettings.sbt$EvaluateSettings$$run0(INode.scala:78)
        at sbt.EvaluateSettings$$anon$3.run(INode.scala:74)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[error] java.util.NoSuchElementException: head of empty stream
[error] Use 'last' for the full log.
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore?
```

The build of toolchain installation executed well. I'm not sure what is problem? I think maybe is sbt, please help.

Comment: `usage: git ls-remote ...` looks suspicious. See where in the Makefile you're doing that and confirm the command is correct. Also try running `evicted` as suggested. I suspect you're missing a "rocket definition file" or something.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade your version of git.

I can't find explicit documentation on which git version is supported by which SBT version, but I confirmed that git version 1.7 fails, while version 2.8 succeeds.